# Flutter-Dart lint to detect unused field

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

I am having the below-unused field and I need to know what is the lint that I need to use in **analysis_option.yaml** file to detect the unused field.

```
final int _padding = 5;
```

I know using **unused_field** we can find this. But my concern is, in a single project consider for example I am having two files viz **file1.dart** and **file2.dart** with different class in each. I have declared the above variable(**_padding**) in file1.dart but never used it any where in the file1.dart and also declared the same variable(**_padding**) in file2.dart and I have used the variable. In this case, in the file1.dart, it has to show lint error i.e **The value of the field '_padding' isn't used**. But it isn't showing in this case.

Can anyone help out to get rid of this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Dharani.

Comment: I just added `unused_field: true` to my analysis_options.yaml and got the warning `'unused_field' is not a recognized lint rule`